# on Submit how to display span value into textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How i can display span value in the textfield using javascript

my code is this

`<span id="count">4</span>`

i want to display 4 in java script on submit

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this on Submit..

```
var spanText = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('txtArear').value=spanText ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SubmitForm(){
    var spanVal = $('span#count').text();
    $('textarea').val(spanVal);
}
```

Try this code on submit

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<span id="count">4</span>
<input type="text" id="result"/>
<input type="button" id="submit"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
$('#result').val($('#count').html());

});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3p6dD/)

Comment: but i think u should focus on my answer. not on English

Comment: I am not telling your answer is wrong or your english is not good, I just  corrected your mistake. So be cool

Comment: ok here when i check the checkbox it count 1 which is store in span now i want to display the span in textbox please help
see here http://jsfiddle.net/3p6dD/2/

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript

```
<span id="count">4</span>
<input type="text" id='place_value'/>
<input type="button" value='Submit' onclick='place_val()' />
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function place_val()
{
    var span_value = document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("place_value").value = span_value;
}
</script>
```

=========================

With JQuery

```
<span id="count">4</span>
<input type="text" id='place_value'/>
<input type="button" value='Submit' id='submit' />
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var span_value = $("#count").html();
    $("#place_value").val(span_value);
});
</script>
```